# How to Convert a integer value to String

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a state drop down on my page and I am saving the ID to the DB column Now when reterving the values I need to retrive the corresponding state name .

Example:

My state is NY
The value saved to DB is 33

when i am pulling the value from the DB to the screen I need to print NY on my screen .

can some assist me on this please?

Comment: Does `ToString()` not work for some reason?

Comment: You mean [`.SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx)? Is the dropdownlist databound?

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to do some sort of `join` in your database query to associate the id with the state name.

Comment: Have you got a table or other mapping that associates the numeric value with the string?

Comment: Can you post your code? I think I agree with @ChrisFarmer, sounds like you need a join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have 33 in your DB you can just grab it from the dropdown that is already on the screen by doing:

```
Dropdown.Items.FindByValue(33).text
```

Comment: I have a State table where I have the State id ,name and code so is this sufficient In addition  i do not have the drop down in the same page where i am trying to use the Name.

Comment: Then when you pull back the dataset from the database you should just find the text of 33 from that dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an associative container like `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dictionary.Add(33, "NY");

string value = dictionary[33]; // "NY"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the corresponding state name, in the DropDown control, at the side, (there is a small arrow there) you can create your datasource, connect to your database then in your table and select the state name column. (if you have one). So when you run it, it will show all the state names in your dropdown.